# how to change from parent-child hierarchical structure to cascading drop-down

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, forms

I have a search function that I would like to tweak so that child under parent appears in different field (a second field) when parent is selected. Currently they are in the same field and appear hierarchical or alphabetical.

for example: Country > state > city > district
They are currently structured like this:

```
`parent`
  `-level 1`
       `--level 2`
          `--- level 3`
            `----level 4`
```

[![They are arranged within the same dropdown field ][1]][1]

so I would like to:
select country (dropdown)
select state, own row (dropdown once country is selected)
select city own (dropdown once state is selected)
Here is my entire code

```
<?php


if (!function_exists('search_hero3_short')) {

    function search_hero3_short() {
        $cat_array = array();
        $cat_array = apply_filters('my_theme_ajax_load_categories', $cat_array, 'cat');
        vc_map(array(
            "name" => __("Search - Hero 3", 'my_theme'),
            "base" => "search_hero3_short_base",
            "category" => __("Theme Shortcodes", 'my_theme'),
            "params" => array(
                array(
                    'group' => __('Shortcode Output', 'my_theme'),
                    'type' => 'custom_markup',
                    'heading' => __('Shortcode Output', 'my_theme'),
                    'param_name' => 'order_field_key',
                    'description' => my_theme_VCImage('hero3.png') . __('Ouput of the shortcode will be look like this.', 'my_theme'),
                ),
                array(
                    "group" => __("Basic", "my_theme"),
                    "type" => "attach_image",
                    "holder" => "bg_img",
                    "class" => "",
                    "heading" => __("Background Image", 'my_theme'),
                    "param_name" => "bg_img",
                    "description" => __("1280x800", 'my_theme'),
                ),
                array(
                    "group" => __("Basic", "my_theme"),
                    "type" => "textfield",
                    "holder" => "div",
                    "class" => "",
                    "heading" => __("Section Title", 'my_theme'),
                    "description" => __("%count% for total ads.", 'my_theme'),
                    "param_name" => "section_title",
                ),
                array(
                    "group" => __("Basic", "my_theme"),
                    "type" => "textfield",
                    "holder" => "div",
                    "class" => "",
                    "heading" => __("Main Title", 'my_theme'),
                    "param_name" => "sub_title",
                ),
                array(
                    "group" => __("Basic", "my_theme"),
                    "type" => "textfield",
                    "holder" => "div",
                    "class" => "",
                    "heading" => __("Button Text", 'my_theme'),
                    "param_name" => "btn_text",
                ),
                array(
                    "group" => __("Basic", "my_theme"),
                    "type" => "textfield",
                    "holder" => "div",
                    "class" => "",
                    "heading" => __("Search Block Text", 'my_theme'),
                    "param_name" => "block_text",
                ),
                array(
                    "group" => __("Basic", "my_theme"),
                    "type" => "textarea",
                    "holder" => "div",
                    "class" => "",
                    "heading" => __("Section Tagline", 'my_theme'),
                    "param_name" => "section_description",
                ),
                array(
                    "group" => __("Location type", "my_theme"),
                    "type" => "dropdown",
                    "heading" => __("Location type", 'my_theme'),
                    "param_name" => "location_type",
                    "admin_label" => true,
                    "value" => array(
                        __('Google', 'my_theme') => 'g_locations',
                        __('Custom Location', 'my_theme') => 'custom_locations',
                    ),
                    'edit_field_class' => 'vc_col-sm-12 vc_column',
                ),
                apply_filters('my_theme_admin_category_load_field', array()),
                array
                    (
                    'group' => __('Categories', 'my_theme'),
                    'type' => 'param_group',
                    'heading' => __('Select Category ( All or Selective )', 'my_theme'),
                    'param_name' => 'cats',
                    'dependency' => array(
                        'element' => 'cat_frontend_switch',
                        'value' => array(''),
                    ),
                    'value' => '',
                    'params' => array
                        ($cat_array)
                ),
                array
                    (
                    'group' => __('Custom Loctions', 'my_theme'),
                    'type' => 'param_group',
                    'heading' => __('Location', 'my_theme'),
                    'param_name' => 'locations',
                    'value' => '',
                    'params' => array
                        (
                        array(
                            "type" => "dropdown",
                            "heading" => __("Location", 'my_theme'),
                            "param_name" => "location",
                            "admin_label" => true,
                            "value" => my_theme_cats('ad_country', 'yes'),
                        ),
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ));
    }

}
add_action('vc_before_init', 'search_hero3_short');
if (!function_exists('search_hero3_short_base_func')) {

    function search_hero3_short_base_func($atts, $content = '') {
           extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'bg_img' => '',
            'section_title' => '',
            'sub_title' => '',
            'section_description' => '',
            'btn_text' => '',
            'block_text' => '',
            'location_type' => '',
            'cats' => '',
            'locations' => '',
                        ), $atts));
        extract($atts);



        global $my_theme_theme;
        $sb_search_page = apply_filters('my_theme_language_page_id', $my_theme_theme['sb_search_page']);
        $sb_post_ad_page = apply_filters('my_theme_language_page_id', $my_theme_theme['sb_post_ad_page']);
        $cats = false;
        $cats_html = '';

        $jax_cat_class = '';
        if (isset($atts['cat_frontend_switch']) && $atts['cat_frontend_switch'] == 'ajax_based') {
            $jax_cat_class = 'sb-load-ajax-cats ';
        } else {


            if (isset($my_theme_elementor) && $my_theme_elementor) {
                $rows = $atts['cats'];
            } else {
                $rows = vc_param_group_parse_atts($atts['cats']);
                $rows = apply_filters('my_theme_validate_term_type', $rows);
            }



            if (is_array($rows) && count($rows) > 0) {
                $cats_html .= '';
                foreach ($rows as $row) {

                    if (isset($my_theme_elementor) && $my_theme_elementor) {
                        $cat_idd = $row;
                    } else {
                        $cat_idd = $row['cat'];
                    }

                    if (isset($cat_idd)) {
                        if ($cat_idd == 'all') {
                            $cats = true;
                            $cats_html = '';
                            break;
                        }
                        $term = get_term($cat_idd, 'ad_cats');
                        $cats_html .= '<option value="' . $cat_idd . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
                    }
                }

                if ($cats) {

                    if (isset($my_theme_theme['display_taxonomies']) && $my_theme_theme['display_taxonomies'] == 'hierarchical') {
                        $args = array(
                            'type' => 'html',
                            'taxonomy' => 'ad_cats',
                            'tag' => 'option',
                            'parent_id' => 0,
                        );
                        $cats_html = apply_filters('my_theme_tax_hierarchy', $cats_html, $args);
                    } else {
                        $args = array('hide_empty' => 0);
                        $args = apply_filters('my_theme_wpml_show_all_posts', $args); // for all lang texonomies
                        $ad_cats = get_terms('ad_cats', $args);
                        foreach ($ad_cats as $cat) {
                            $cats_html .= '<option value="' . $cat->term_id . '">' . $cat->name . '</option>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // For custom locations
        $locations_html = '';
        $args_loc = array('hide_empty' => 0);

        $loc_flag = FALSE;
        if (isset($my_theme_elementor) && $my_theme_elementor) {
            $rows = (isset($atts['locations']) && $atts['locations'] != '' ? $atts['locations'] : '');
            if (isset($rows[0]) && $rows[0] == 'all' && isset($location_type) && $location_type == 'custom_locations') {
                $loc_flag = TRUE;
            }
        } else {
            $rows = vc_param_group_parse_atts(isset($atts['locations']) && $atts['locations'] != '' ? $atts['locations'] : '');
            if (isset($rows[0]['location']) && $rows[0]['location'] == 'all' && isset($location_type) && $location_type == 'custom_locations') {
                $loc_flag = TRUE;
            }
        }
        
        if ($loc_flag) {
            $locations_html .= ' <option value="">' . esc_html__('Select location', 'my_theme') . ' </option> ';

            if (isset($my_theme_theme['display_taxonomies']) && $my_theme_theme['display_taxonomies'] == 'hierarchical') {

                $args = array(
                    'type' => 'html',
                    'taxonomy' => 'ad_country',
                    'tag' => 'option',
                    'parent_id' => 0,
                );
                $locations_html = apply_filters('my_theme_tax_hierarchy', $locations_html, $args);
            } else {
                $ad_country_arr = get_terms('ad_country', $args_loc);
                if (isset($ad_country_arr) && count($ad_country_arr) > 0) {
                    foreach ($ad_country_arr as $loc_value) {
                        $locations_html .= ' <option value="' . intval($loc_value->term_id) . '">' . esc_html($loc_value->name) . ' </option> ';
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (count((array) $rows) > 0 ) {
                $locations_html .= '';
                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                    
                    if (isset($my_theme_elementor) && $my_theme_elementor) {
                        $loc_ids = isset($row) ? $row : '';
                    }else{
                       $loc_ids = isset($row['location']) ? $row['location'] : ''; 
                    } 
                    
                    if (isset($loc_ids) && $loc_ids != '') {
                        $term = get_term($loc_ids, 'ad_country');
                        if(isset($term->name)) {
                        $locations_html .= ' <option value="' . $loc_ids . '">' . $term->name . '</option> ';
                    }}
                }
            }
        }

        $style = '';
        if ($bg_img != "") {
            $bgImageURL = my_theme_returnImgSrc($bg_img);


            $style = ( $bgImageURL != "" ) ? ' style="background: url(' . $bgImageURL . '); width: 100%;height: 750px;background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-attachment: scroll;background-position: center center;"' : "";
        }
        $contries_script = '';
        $location_type_html = '';
        if (isset($location_type) && $location_type == 'custom_locations') {
            $location_type_html = '<select class="category form-control" name="country_id" data-placeholder="' . __('Select Location', 'my_theme') . '">
               <option label="' . __('Select Location', 'my_theme') . '" value="">' . __('Select Location', 'my_theme') . '</option>
               ' . $locations_html . '
               </select>';
        } else {
            ob_start();
            my_theme_load_search_countries();
            $contries_script = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();

            wp_enqueue_script('google-map-callback');
            $location_type_html = '<input class="form-control" name="location"  id="sb_user_address" placeholder="' . __('Location...', 'my_theme') . '"  type="text">';
        }
        $count_posts = wp_count_posts('ad_post');

        $main_title = '';
        $section_title_html = '';
        if (isset($section_title) && $section_title != '') {
            $main_title = str_replace('%count%', '<b>' . $count_posts->publish . '</b>', $section_title);
            $section_title_html = '<div class="classified-text"><h1>' . $main_title . '</h1></div>';
        }

        $sub_title_html = '';
        if (isset($sub_title) && $sub_title != '') {
            $sub_title_html = '<div class="classified-short-text"><p>' . $sub_title . '</p></div>';
        }
        $btn_text_html = '';
        if (isset($btn_text) && $btn_text != '') {
            $btn_text_html = '<div class="ad-button-r1"><a href="' . get_the_permalink($sb_post_ad_page) . '" class="btn btn-theme color-white">' . $btn_text . '</a></div>';
        }

        return $contries_script . '<section class="ads-listing-section"' . $style . '>
                                  <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                      <div class="col-lg-7 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                                        <div class="classified-ad-listing">
                                          ' . $section_title_html . '
                                          ' . $sub_title_html . '
                                          ' . $btn_text_html . '
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                                        <div class="form-listing">
                                          <form class="form-join" action="' . urldecode(get_the_permalink($sb_search_page)) . '">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                           <label for="exampleInputEmail1">' . __('Title', 'my_theme') . '</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="ad_title" placeholder="' . __('What Are You Looking For...', 'my_theme') . '" type="text"> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">' . __('Select Category', 'my_theme') . '</label>
                                            <select class="' . $jax_cat_class . 'category form-control" name="cat_id" data-placeholder="' . __('Select Category', 'my_theme') . '"><option label="' . __('Select Category', 'my_theme') . '" value="">' . __('Select Category', 'my_theme') . '</option>' . $cats_html . '</select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">' . __('Location', 'my_theme') . '</label>' . $location_type_html . '</div>
                                            ' . apply_filters('my_theme_form_lang_field', false) . '
                                            <div class="button-blocks"><button class="btn btn-theme btn-block" type="submit">' . __('search', 'my_theme') . '</button></div>
                                          </form>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </section>';
    }

}
if (function_exists('my_theme_add_code')) {
    my_theme_add_code('search_hero3_short_base', 'search_hero3_short_base_func');
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C79pG.png
```

Comment: I managed to replicate the entry field but still couldn't manage to separate theme Node > child.